# Wireless/WiFi connection keeps disconnecting in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have installed Ububtu 14.04 since a while and I have problem with my WiFi that randomly disconnects and after disconnecting does not work for a long time. I run the script in the official answer [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

and this is the result

```
> Blockquote

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 13 Oct 2014 19:20 CEST +0200

Booted last: 13 Oct 2014 18:12 CEST +0200

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, 

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

20:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02eb]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6406 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

brcmsmac              563041  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
b43                   387371  0 
mac80211              630653  2 b43,brcmsmac
cfg80211              484040  3 b43,brcmsmac,mac80211
ssb                    62379  1 b43
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            18168  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
bcma                   52096  2 b43,brcmsmac
wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.111  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:b9ff:fec4:4092/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1533 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:551292 (551.2 KB)  TX bytes:272479 (272.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search casaHobbit

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.111
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/I ragazzi delle ragazze]] (600 root)
[connection] id=I ragazzi delle ragazze | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=I ragazzi delle ragazze | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Rome (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[brcmsmac]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     43D6897F7EB716081DF69BE
depends:        bcma,mac80211,brcmutil,cfg80211,cordic
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        38:F3:B6:C6:3A:85:AF:FD:FB:BE:0E:53:33:9D:F8:E0:C6:B6:C9:D5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[brcmutil]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver utilities.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     E81EE4CBB6A7A689150D93D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        38:F3:B6:C6:3A:85:AF:FD:FB:BE:0E:53:33:9D:F8:E0:C6:B6:C9:D5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     7ABBDDCA84C087640B27AE6
depends:        bcma,ssb,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        38:F3:B6:C6:3A:85:AF:FD:FB:BE:0E:53:33:9D:F8:E0:C6:B6:C9:D5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B822641624778B987844F6F
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        38:F3:B6:C6:3A:85:AF:FD:FB:BE:0E:53:33:9D:F8:E0:C6:B6:C9:D5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        38:F3:B6:C6:3A:85:AF:FD:FB:BE:0E:53:33:9D:F8:E0:C6:B6:C9:D5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     3DE188310F77C566C2E8CB3
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        38:F3:B6:C6:3A:85:AF:FD:FB:BE:0E:53:33:9D:F8:E0:C6:B6:C9:D5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     E41B811D88783DD5BC38565
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        38:F3:B6:C6:3A:85:AF:FD:FB:BE:0E:53:33:9D:F8:E0:C6:B6:C9:D5
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwlps=0

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4353 (brcmsmac)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 3503.534359] bcma: bus0: Some GPIOs are still in use.
[ 3503.537985] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address> by local choice (reason=3)
[ 3503.689989] brcmsmac bcma0:0: wl0: brcms_c_watchdog: dead chip
[ 3504.037739] brcmsmac bcma0:0: ops->tx called while down (repeated 3 times)
[ 3504.038196] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
[ 3504.038206] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
[ 3504.038211] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
[ 3504.038216] brcmsmac bcma0:0: wl0: brcms_c_wme_setparams : no-clock (repeated 4 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```